# How can I get cassandra-driver onto PYTHONPATH?

Tags: macos, bash, cassandra, pythonpath, datomic

I am trying to set up Cassandra with Datomic and when I run the command `cqlsh -f ~/datomic/bin/cql/cassandra-user.cql -u uname -p pword` I get an error that says

```
Python: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Module load path: [
'/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.1.2/bin', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cql-1.4.0-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thrift-0.9.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ccm-2.0.2-py2.7.egg',
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tailer-0.3-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psutil-2.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Error: No module named cassandra
```

I have installed the driver using `pip install cassandra-driver` attempted putting the path that the driver is located in on my PYTHONPATH, using `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I have even copied the driver into one of the directories that are already listed on my path. No luck. Could somebody help me to get past this hurdle?

Cassandra was installed with homebrew here `/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.1.2/`

Datomic is here 
`~/datomic`

cassandra-driver is here
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: I haven't yet and just kind of gave up. There are a few ways that you can install Cassandra and set up your paths. I went with homebrew and could not solve this problem. I recommend going with ccm / datastax to get a local cluster going. I have also asked this similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162885/how-can-i-set-up-a-superuser-account-on-cassandra-with-homebrew-build) particularly  related to homebrew.

Comment: And here is the [datomic tutorial](http://juliangamble.com/blog/2013/12/27/steps-to-setup-datomic-on-a-cassandra-cluster-on-macos-mavericks/) I was following. I got up to the point that I had to add a superuser for cassandra and hit a roadblock

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use the mac system python distribution, are you? While theres nothing wrong with that, its recommended to leave the system distribution alone and install a separate python using `brew install python`. Afterwards try installing cqlsh using `pip install cql` while making sure to use the brew pip version (check using `which pip` -> should point to /usr/local).

Comment: which pip returns /usr/local/bin/pip.