# How can I set up a superuser account on Cassandra with homebrew build?

Tags: python, bash, cassandra, homebrew, sudo

I have installed cassandra with homebrew and am trying to create a superuser admin account. when I type `sudo cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra` I get this error:

```
Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH.
You might try "pip install cassandra-driver".
Python: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Module load path: ['/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.1.2/bin', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cql-1.4.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thrift-0.9.2-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ccm-2.0.2-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tailer-0.3-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psutil-2.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Error: No module named cassandra
```

when I do it without sudo, I am allowed into cqlsh with the default login. Problem is that when I type `CREATE USER admn WITH PASSWORD 'pw' SUPERUSER;`, this gets returned:

`code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers are allowed to perform CREATE USER queries"`

When I saw this I was like, no prob, and got into my cassandra.yaml file, located in `/usr/local/etc/cassandra` and changed `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator`
to `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`. I saved the file went back to the cqlsh and tried again. Same result. Can somebody please tell me what to do to set up new users?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track.  The default superuser account is username 'cassandra' password 'cassandra' and you are appropriately configuring the authenticator.

What's missing is that after changing the cassandra.yaml file, you need to restart cassandra in order for the Authenticator change to take effect.  Note that you should also change the authorizer to 'CassandraAuthorizer'.

If you have a multi-node cluster, you should make this change on all nodes and you should also increase the replication factor on the system_auth keyspace in order to allow auth to continue working after the node owning the data goes down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There isn't a cluster at this point. I'm just getting started trying to get things set up on my localhost. I have changed the authorizer and restarted cassandra using  `launchctl <unload/load> /usr/local/opt/cassandra/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra.plist`. but am still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the homebrew installation of cassandra (I usually use CCM or build from source).  Can you confirm that cassandra is actually restarted and that the cassandra.yaml file you are using is the one being parsed? (should show the cassandra.yaml file it's reading from in system.log)

Comment: I also downloaded ccm, but when I run `ccm create test -v 2.1.2 -n 3 -s` I get the output `BUILD FAILED
.../repository/2.1.2/build.xml:346: artifact:pom doesn't support the "groupId" attribute`. and I couldn't troubleshoot it. I'll look into the system.log and get back...

Comment: I can't find system.log anywhere. There are two paths  -`/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/2.1.2/` and `/usr/local/opt/cassandra/` - that have the same exact contents. Then there is a third: `/usr/local/etc/cassandra`. I'm not sure if the last one is part of the homebrew installation and that is where the `cassandra.yaml` file is. I'm willing to use ccm if that is easier.

Comment: I'd recommend using CCM, mostly because I'm more familiar with it, and also because it makes testing multi-node setups very easy.  You could run a command like 'ccm node1 showlog' to see the logs instead of hunting them down.  With regards to your error, I'm not sure what that error means, but i'd check to make sure that you have a newer version of ant installed.

Comment: I do have the latest ant but it is also the home brew installation. Downloading all this homebrew stuff seemed like a good idea at the time, but I'm starting to regret it.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the issue to create a new user, after connecting cassandra node from cqlsh as cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra.

## Solution worked out to me is:

1. Edit the cassandra.yaml and replaced the authenticator and authorizer values as below.

//authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

## authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator

//authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

## authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer

2. Re start the cassandra node
3. connect from cqlsh with cassandra/cassandra credentials

4.Watched out a system.log(tail -f system.log), you should see following message.

INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2015-04-23 11:02:03,973  PasswordAuthenticator.java:215 - PasswordAuthenticator created default user 'cassandra'

INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2015-04-23 11:02:03,987 Auth.java:277 - Created default superuser 'cassandra'

5. Before to this I didn't have "system_auth" key space, after this change now am able to see "system_auth" key space and "credentials" table.

Answer (score 2):

Note: **for Cassandra 2.2 and later**

"CREATE USER is supported for backwards compatibility. Authentication and authorization for Cassandra 2.2 and later are based on ROLES, and CREATE ROLE should be used."

Take a look at: [Creating a new user using ROLE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/create_user_r.html)

---

Answering your question, this worked for me:

In the configuration file of Cassandra, **cassandra.yaml** modify these lines:

Comment this line:

> authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

and replace for:

> authenticator: **PasswordAuthenticator**

Comment this line:

> authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

and replace for:

> authorizer: **CassandraAuthorizer**

After that, you can create your own super user:

**create user *your_user_name* with password '*your_password*' superuser;**